# Find Nth element from the end in Scala using recursive tail

Tags: scala, recursion

I am new to Scala and I am trying to understand this program below. Particularly I don't understand the line

```scala
case _ :: tail        =>
            lastNthR(count - 1,
              if (count > 0) resultList else resultList.tail,
              tail)
```

Lets say I have to find last 2nd element that is 6, the code becomes `lastNthR(2-1=1`?, as 1>0 it should get `resultList` am I right here? else `resultlist.tail, tail`?

I don't get it. Can someone please explain it to me. I am scratching my head for a long time. Here is full code:

```scala
  def lastNthRecursive[A](n: Int, ls: List[A]): A = {
      def lastNthR(count: Int, resultList: List[A], curList: List[A]): A =
        curList match {
          case Nil if count > 0 => throw new NoSuchElementException
          case Nil              => resultList.head
          case _ :: tail        =>
            lastNthR(count - 1,
              if (count > 0) resultList else resultList.tail,
              tail)
        }

      if (n <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException
      else lastNthR(n, ls, ls)
  }

  println(lastNthRecursive(2,List(4,5,6,7)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very interesting example!

It uses a list and a copy of itself to know when to stop walking trough the elements of the list. This is what happens when running your example, on each call to `lastNthR`:

```
count = 2
resultList = List(4, 5, 6, 7)
curList = List(4, 5, 6, 7)

count = 1
resultList = List(4, 5, 6, 7)
curList = List(5, 6, 7)

count = 0
resultList = List(4, 5, 6, 7)
curList = List(6, 7)

count = -1
resultList = List(5, 6, 7)
curList = List(7)

count = -2
resultList = List(6, 7)
curList = List()
```

As you can see, on each step, it subtracts one to `count`. While `count` is greater than zero, it won't affect `resultList`, which as its name states, is the list that we will use to get the final result. However, on each step, the first element from `curList` is removed. The function executes until `curList` runs out of elements. However, we have started removing elements from `resultList` just after we have removed the first N (in this example, 2) elements from `curList`. This way, we will run out of elements from `curList` while we still have the last 2 elements from `resultList`.

In a more graphic way, the intended effect is as if we moved the `resultList` 2 places to the right:

```
count: 2
resultList =       4, 5, 6, 7
curList    = 4, 5, 6, 7
```

Then, we start removing elements, one by one, until we run out of elements from `curList`, which is what the block that you pointed out does:

```
count: 1
resultList =    4, 5, 6, 7
curList    = 5, 6, 7

count: 0
resultList = 4, 5, 6, 7
curList    = 6, 7
```

When `count` is zero or lower, we start removing items from `resultList` too:

```
count: -1
resultList = 5, 6, 7
curList    = 7

count: -2
resultList = 6, 7
curList    =
```

This way, when we run out of items from `curList`, we still have the 2 elements left from `resultList`, so we only need to get the first of them. This is done with the code:

```
curList match {
  // ...
  case Nil => resultList.head
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you Guillermo. I have a question here so when the count becomes 0 then it should return resultlist.last right?I was going thru your answer you gave the result as 4,5,6,7 why it is not 5,6,7 from the code `code if (count > 0) resultList else resultList.tail `code

Comment: @user2708013 nope, when the count becomes 0, it starts removing the head items from `resultList` by passing its `tail` to the next recursive call. At this point, the recursive calls have already removed 2 elements from `curList`. When `curList` is empty, it will the return the head (first element) of `resultList`, which will contain the Nth last element.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is a typo in the title or did you miss that but this method (as the name suggests) finds the `N`-th element ***from the end*** (or in a reverse order) starting with `1` as the very last element (which is an uncommon notation in programming, typically indices start with `0` instead).

I think you messed up with formatting. Let's re-write this code into an equivalent form:

```scala
if(count > 0) {
 lastNthR(count - 1,
          resultList,
          tail)
}
else {
 lastNthR(count - 1,
          resultList.tail,
          tail)
}
```

In other words in your code the `if(count > 0)` statement affects calculation of the second parameter in the `lastNthR` call while the first parameter (`count - 1`) and the third parameter (`tail`) are "fixed", this is what comma (`,`) at the end of the line with that `if` means.

Logically this code works in two stages:

1. At the first stage when `if(count > 0)` holds true, we reduce the `curList` and `count` by 1 each until `count` becomes 0.
2. At the second stage when `if(count > 0)` is false, we reduce `curList` and `resultList` by 1 each until `curList` is empty.

In other words the algorithm says that find the `n`-th element from the end is the same as finding `length(list) - n`-th element from the start. The first stage finds this `length(list) - n` value (in term of a list of that length) and then the second stage does a search from the start.

You can re-write that code separating the stages explicitly in two different methods:

```scala
def lastNthRecursive[A](n: Int, ls: List[A]): A = {
  // stage 1
  // note, there is actually a very similar a standard method on a List 
  // but it doesn't fail in case of an overshot (n > length(list))
  def dropN(count: Int, curList: List[A]): List[A] = curList match {
    case _ if (count == 0) => curList // important to be above the Nil case
    case Nil => throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(s"$n is more than the list length")
    case _ :: tail => dropN(count - 1, tail)
  }

  // stage 2      
  def dropAll(longList:List[A], shortList:List[A]):List[A] = shortList match {
      case Nil => longList
      case _  => dropAll(longList.tail, shortList.tail)    
  }

  if (n < 0) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(s"$n is less than 0")
  else {
    val shortenedList = dropN(n, ls)
    val resultList = dropAll(ls, shortenedList)
    resultList.head
  } 
}
```

P.S. I don't like the fact that exceptions are inconsistent `IllegalArgumentException` vs `NoSuchElementException` and provide no textual description at all. Also there is IMHO a better exception for this case - `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 1):

Way to get nth element(o indexed) from a List:

```
def get[A] (n: Int, list: List[A]): A = {
   @scala.annotation.tailrec
   def go(acc: Int, li: List[A]): A = {
     if(acc == n) List.head(li)
     else go(acc+1, tail(li))
   }

  if(n > List.length(list) - 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException("indexincompatible with List length");
  go(0, list)
}
```

To get nth element from last, call it with index calculated from start.